# A very basic question about sequences in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Sorry for this very simple question, but it gets me really confused.

So far, I have perceived the sequences in $\Bbb{R}^n$ as sequences where every element is a point with $n$ numbers. However, I have recently started to get confused, so I felt like I need to be confirmed to be sure that I understand the concepts and the notations correctly.

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ is an infinite sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ if every $x_i$ is in $\Bbb{R}$- that is $\Bbb{R}^1$. However, I suppose, it becomes a sequence in $\Bbb{R}^n$ if every $x_i$ is a point like $(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ where $y_i$ is in $\Bbb{R}$ for all $i$.

I for some reason got this confusion after I attempted to prove that $\Bbb{R}^n$ endowed with euclidian metric is a complete space- I simply could not figure out what I am supposed to subtract from what when using euclidian metric and how to show that satisfying Cauchy criterion implies convergence.

Comment: Your statements and notation are correct. If $x_i$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R_n$, then each $x_i$ is of the form $(y_1, y_2, \ldots y_n)$. One common notation is to write $x_i = (x_{i,1}, x_{i,2}, \ldots, x_{i, n})$. One way to visualize this is to think of the sequence $x_i$ as a matrix with $n$ columns and infinitely many rows (or vice versa).

Comment: Nice to hear that and thank you! Can we also say that every element of the sequence in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a finite sequence in $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, you can call $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)$ a finite sequence (of length $n$) if you like, or perhaps somewhat more standard, you can call it an $n$-tuple. More formally, it's a function with domain $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots n\}$ and codomain $\mathbb R$.